# Vb.net access insert query into table with relations

Tags: vb.net, relationship

Can someone explain me how to make an insert query to insert data into a table with relations?
I have two tables: lets call them "Users" and "Data", in the first table i store the username and the password, in the second one i have all the info about the user body measurements, and i connected them with a relation of 1 to many, where 1 user can have many rows of body measurements.

So here comes my question, how do i insert the measurements data into the table "Data" for the specified user only?

Img of table relations: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zL4MM.jpg

How can i do it? I tried the following query but its not working

```
INSERT INTO Data ([Thigh], [Hips], [Waist], [Abdomen], [Chest], [Tricep], [Chest], [Gender], [Weight], [Height], [Age]) VALUES (30, 45, 30, 40, 60, 25, 50, Male, 70, 180, 20)"
```

Comment: *"its not working"*. That is NEVER an adequate explanation of anything. You need to provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem. Also, you've tagged this as a VB.NET question but there is nothing about VB.NET anywhere in what you have posted.

Comment: If you are inserting data into multiple related tables then you need multiple `INSERT` statements. You would generally have auto-generated primary keys and so you insert into the parent table first, retrieve the PK and then insert that into the child table with the rest of the data. You would generally use a transaction to ensure that the entire process either succeeds or fails as a unit. You need to research each of those steps and show us that you have made an attempt to implement them, then explain exactly where and how things don't go as you expected.

Comment: Put apostrophes around `Male`

Comment: If you are using vb.net, I doubt that you are writing the Insert with literal values. Please show the code you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to know the ID of the user (who will have the new data).  Specifically, you need their ID from the User table. Your "table relations" diagram shows this relationship, which means it is being enforced.

For example, if I was user.ID 13, the INSERT statement would look like this:

```
INSERT INTO Data (User_ID, [Thigh], [Hips], [Waist], [Abdomen], [Chest], 
   [Tricep], [Chest], [Gender], [Weight], [Height], [Age]) 
VALUES (13, 30, 45, 30, 40, 60, 
   25, 50, 'Male', 70, 180, 20)
```

Comment: Works perfectly, i made a select query to get the ID of the user using the app and then i user the insert query with the ID i just got. Thanks!